# Why am I receiving different values on two machines when sending data across a network?

Tags: c++, networking

I have a client-server architecture with the client in C# on Windows and the Server in C++ on Linux. I am currently sending an integer as bytes across a network which is received by the server which is then echoed back to the client as bytes.

I am constructing the byte array using

```
    byte[] rotationBytes = new byte[4];
    rotationBytes[0] = (byte) (rotation >> 24);
    rotationBytes[1] = (byte)(rotation >> 16);
    rotationBytes[2] = (byte)(rotation >> 8);
    rotationBytes[3] = (byte)(rotation);
```

And on the server it is constructed using

```
    char data[4];

    udp::endpoint senderEndpoint;

    size_t length = udpSocket.receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(data, 4), senderEndpoint);

    int rotation = (int)(data[0] << 24 |
        data[1] << 16 |
        data[2] << 8 |
        data[3]);
```

When the server receives some values, it outputs the incorrect value, however when this value is printed out in the front end it is as expected. An example of this can be seen below.

```
Send from C# front end: 45
C++ server receives: 45

Send from C# front end: 90
C++ server receives: 90

Send from C# front end: 135
C++ server receives: -121

Send from C# front end: 180
C++ server receives: -76

Send from C# front end: 225
C++ server receives: -31

Send from C# front end: 270
C++ server receives: 270
```

Some of the data is correct and some is not. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like your `char` is signed and so gets sign extended when converted to `int`.

Might work better with an `unsigned char`.